# Average monthly pageviews from Google Analytics in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio, google-data-studio-charts

I'm using a Google Analytics property as a data source in Google Data Studio.

I have a table where each row is a section of the site (The table dimension is "Page path level 1").

I'd like each row of the table to have (among other things) the average monthly pageviews for the selected date range.  That is, I want to know:

`(The total number of pageviews in the selected period) / ([days in the selected period]/30.42)`

That's all easily done in a computed field *except* "days in the selected period".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new field under metric with formula "Pageviews / Count(Date)"

[image]